# C# IF statement is not excluding strings

Tags: c#, if-statement, readfile

So the problem is : I want to read from file and exclude certain strings( i am inexperienced so I decided to use IF so i want to exclude the strings Name, facultyNumber and etc. but it doesn't exclude them for some reason ? (I've tried to remove the spaces from the if statement)

```
 public void read()
            {
               string[] textes = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\sashk\Source\Repos\ConsoleApp6\ConsoleApp6\save.txt", Encoding.Default);
                double[] gread = new double[] { 1, 2, 3 };
                List<string> texts = new List<string>();
                int i= 0;
                int z = 0;
                foreach (string text in textes)
                {
                    string[] words = textes[i].Split(' ');
                    for (int j = 0; j < words.Length; j++)
                    {
                        if (!words[j].Equals(" Name: ") || !words[j].Equals(" FacultyNumber: ") || !words[j].Equals(" Grades: ") || !words[j].Equals(" AverageGrade: "))
                        {
                            texts.Add(words[j]);
                        }
                    }
                    //  for (int j = 2; j < texts.Count; j++)
                    //  {
                    //      gread[z] = Convert.ToDouble(texts[j]); 
                    //  }
                    //  addStudent(texts[0], Convert.ToInt32(texts[1]), gread);
                    for (int j = 0; j < 40; j++)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(texts[j]);
                    }
                    i++;
                }
```

The content of the file is this:

```
> Name: asd FacultyNumber: 2 Grades: 1,23  4,56  7,89   AverageGrade: 4,56
 Name: as FacultyNumber: 4 Grades: 1  5  9   AverageGrade: 5
 Name: ad FacultyNumber: 3 Grades: 2  4  7   AverageGrade: 4,33333333333333
 Name: ddd00 FacultyNumber: 1 Grades: 12  15  99   AverageGrade: 42
```

Comment: The error i get is because it passes the strings that i stated i don't want to get passed in the if

Comment: Remove the spaces - `!words[j].Equals(" Name: ")` should be `!words[j].Equals("Name:")`

Comment: The correct answer is BOTH Zohar Peled's comment above AND OmG's answer. The split removes the spaces from the words AND the negated ||'s are incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Contains` like this:

```
var excluded = new[] { "Name:", "FacultyNumber:", "Grades:", "AverageGrade:" }; 

foreach (string text in textes) 
{
    string[] words = textes[i].Split(' ');
    for (int j = 0; j < words.Length; j++) 
    {
        if (!excluded.Contains(words[j]))
        {
            texts.Add(words[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

But I think you can do it with LINQ. The code will be much cleaner:

```
string[] textes = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\sashk\Source\Repos\ConsoleApp6\ConsoleApp6\save.txt", Encoding.Default);

var excluded = new[] { "Name:", "FacultyNumber:", "Grades:", "AverageGrade:" }; 

var texts = textes.SelectMany(x => x.Split(' ').Where(y => !excluded.Contains(y)));

foreach(string word in texts)
{
    Console.WriteLine(word);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should `&&` all conditions. As the preference of `||` is from left to right, if the most left condition would be true the other conditions will not be considered. Hence, if a word passed this part of condition `!words[j].Equals(" Name: ")`, it will pass the whole of the condition. Therefore, if there is a word likes `FacultyNumber` or `Grades` passed the first condition and you will not get what you specified. You can modify your code likes the following:

```
if (!(words[j].Equals(" Name: ") || 
      words[j].Equals(" FacultyNumber: ") || 
      words[j].Equals(" Grades: ") || 
      words[j].Equals(" AverageGrade: ")))
```

Comment: No string can be equal to " Name: " and to " FacultyNumber" at the same time! So the whole condition will always be true.

Comment: @XouDo you're right. It was a little mistake. It's updated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly new to programming and don't know if there's any downside to using the string.Replace method, but this is how I would do it.

```
public void read()
{
    string[] textes = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\sashk\Source\Repos\ConsoleApp6\ConsoleApp6\save.txt", Encoding.Default);
    List<string> texts = new List<string>();

    for (int i = 0; i < textes.Lenght; i++)
    {
        texts.Add(textes[i].Replace(" Name: ", ""));
        texts.Add(textes[i].Replace(" FacultyNumber: ", ""));
        texts.Add(textes[i].Replace(" Grades: ", ""));
        texts.Add(textes[i].Replace(" AverageGrade: ", ""));
    }
    foreach (string text in texts)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(text);
    }
}
```

Comment: This will mean that every input line is repeated 4 times, with different keywords removed. Do all replaced on the same string, to remove all. But you are right, this is a solution to "remove keywords", as stated in the question